# Sharepoint permissions (user should able to submit the form, but not able to edit/delete it)?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I'm new to info path-share point. I want following functionality in my form:

1. user should able to submit the form.
2. but should not able to edit/delete the form .

When permission level is "contribute" , user is able to submit the form, however can edit/delete it
When permission is "read" user can't edit/delete the from, but can not submit even.

Please let me know if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a custom permission level.

In SharePoint 2010, go to Site Settings > Site permissions > Permission Levels. First, take a look at the Contribute permission level. Make a note of which permissions are checked. Go back and click Add a Permission Level. Create a permission level like Contribute less editing and deleting.

Once the new permission level is in place, go to the permissions for your list and click Stop Inheriting Permissions. Change the permission levels of the desired users or groups from Contribute to your new permission level.

Answer (score 0):

But what if you have the same requestor, coming back to edit their form after certain steps in the "Approval Chain"?

For instance: After their Supervisor Approves this request, they need to include Additional Requesting Details.

There has to be some way to state: "Can create and edit items that you have created but cannot edit items that others have created".

Comment: Not really an answer, but no downvote since you can't comment yet.